# React - how to only show half of a background image on tablet and 1/4 on phone

Tags: html, css

**Goal**
I have a background image that on a computer or laptop browser I want it to show 100% width, but I only want it to show 1/2 of the image if you cut it vertically on tablet and if it's phone I want it to show 1/4 of the image if you cut it vertically.

**What I've Tried**
Tried using clip-path in CSS but that makes it horizontal scroll enabled which I don't want.

[On browser should look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/np7c0.png)

[On Tablet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WdQpn.png)

[On Phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8EQU.png)

On tablet and phone the rest of the image should not be visible via scroll. It should only allow vertical scroll and that's simply the background.

Comment: Share the code you have so far, what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with media queries and the `background-size` property.

```css
/* Default (mobile) */
body {
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/np7c0.png) no-repeat;
  background-size: 400%;
}

/* Tablet and up */
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  body {
    background-size: 200%;
  }
}

/* Desktop and up */
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  body {
    background-size: 100%;
  }
}
```

Here's a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/zxqcgkLp/

---

Note: you may need to play around with your breakpoints, depending on your specific needs. Here's a useful guide from CSS-Tricks that shows common device breakpoints:

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Comment: An alternative approach would be to produce separate image assets optimized for each device type and use media queries to change `background-image` instead of `background-size`.